# A function to decrypt a XORed string with a key made out of all possible combinations of lowercase letters

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I have received a challenge and now I'm a bit stuck. Basically, I got a list of ASCII codes that were XORed. We KNOW that the key is of size 5, lowercase English letters. I have read different methods to decrypt this, from frequency analysis and the usage of tools for python (like xortool), but I didn't manage to make them work. Xortool was used with arguments -l 5 -o and I received a hundred results of gibberish sadly.

For this example I'm going to use only the first 5 codes of said ASCII. The full message is of length 1125.

```
xor_min = ["49","29","1","67","42"]
```

This, converted in binary is:

```
converted_min = ['00110001', '00011101', '00000001', '01000011', '00101010']
```

Then I made a separate list containing all the letters in the alphabet, lowercase, in binary form.

```
alph = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
bin_key = convert_to_bin((convert_to_ascii(alph)))
```

Up until this point everything works perfectly. Now what I want to do is create out of bin_key a key of size 5 containing all the possible combinations out of 26.

```
key = list(itertools.combinations(bin_key, 5))
```

Ok. Now key contains 65780 elements, in a list of tuples. Next step would be that for each element in xor_min the XOR operation should be made with a tuple from the key list. This is the part where I have problems. Here is my whole code:

```
def xor_list(xor_encrypted, max_key):
       key = list(itertools.combinations(max_key, 5))
       possible_xor = ['' for x in range(0, len(key))]
       i = 0
       for element in range(0, len(max_key)):
           if i == 5:
                  i = 0
           possible_xor[element] = operator.xor(int(xor_encrypted[i]), int(key[element][i]))
           i+=1
       return possible_xor


alph = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
bin_key = convert_to_bin((convert_to_ascii(alph)))

xor_min = ["49","29","1","67","42"]
converted_min = convert_to_bin(xor_min)
```

print (xor_list(converted_min, bin_key))

The Output I get is: `[1140048, 1106871, 1100010, 2067215, 1132123, 1140048, 1106871, 1100010, 2067215, 1132452, 1140048, 1106871, 1100010, 2067215, 1140073, 1140048, 1106871, 1100010, 2067215, 1145162, 1140048, 1106871, 1100010, 2067214, 1132122, 1140048, '', '', '', '', '',.........]`

I know I should convert the ints to binary, but if I use the bin function in the operator.xor I get an error message:

```
    possible_xor[element] = operator.xor(bin(int(xor_encrypted[i])), bin(int(key[element][i])))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

If you have any questions / clarifications needed, please let me know. Also, if you have other/ better solutions, please don't be afraid to share. With the result of the decrypted 5 letters I would skim them over to see what would make sense. It should be the beginning of a link or an English word.

Comment: I don't understand why you convert the items in `xor_min`to binary strings, and then treat those strings as if they were decimal numbers with `int(xor_encrypted[i])`. Also, `itertools.combinations` creates sorted combinations without repetition. If you _really_ want all possible combinations of length 5 from a list or string named `a` you need the Cartesian product: `product(a, repeat=5)`. For 26 letters, that gives you `26**5 = 11881376` different combinations. So it's probably best to iterate directly over the `product` iterable, rather than storing its output in a list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you think that `itertools.combinations(max_key, 5)` is enough?
What if secret key contains repeating letters for example "aaaaa"? Your method is not checking such variants.

But if condition says that key is not contains repeating letters then it is OK and you can try this code to see all possible variants of decryption:

```
import itertools
import string
encrypted = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104]
alph = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
bin_key = [b for b in map(ord, alph)]
for i in itertools.combinations(bin_key, 5):
    print([chr(i[k] ^ encrypted[k]) for k in range(5)])
```

Comment: It seems I missed the fact that I needed product instead of combinations. Thank you. I tried what you did above, but the results of itertools.product is a list of tuples and each element is a string. When I try to do this I get an error that str ^ str does not work. 

 Also, I think I need to convert the key back to binary after I make the product. So I have a list of tuples of binaries instead. Then I can do a XOR operation with it. Correct?

Comment: Tried something like this:
`def xor_list2(xor_encrypted, key):
    possible_xor = []
    for i in key:
        possible_xor.append([chr(i[k] ^ xor_encrypted[k]) for k in range(1125)])
    return possible_xor`

1125 - being the true length of the message.

Comment: Tried something like this for the conversion, keep getting memory errors sadly. `def convert_to_bin2(key_list):
    converted_list = []
    for tup in range(0, len(key_list)):
        for element in range(0, 5):
            converted_list.append(bin(int(key_list[tup][element], base=2)))
    return converted_list`

Comment: @Vanayad If you need to convert string values to int and values in encrypted list is storing as string like ['100', '101', '102'] you can simly to add int conversion like this: `print([chr(i[k] ^ int(encrypted[k])) for k in range(5)])`. But if there is binary format of bytes like ['1100100', '1100101', '1100110'], then you can use second argument of int() function: `print([chr(i[k] ^ int(encrypted[k], 2)) for k in range(5)])`